# How to update message.content every new message in Discord?

Tags: python, discord.py

The question was badly worded, but for a discord bot I am making, it looks for "s!rps" in message.content, and if "s!rps" is sent in the chat, it asks for Rock, Paper, or Scissors. I want it to update the message content every new message, but message.content stays as s!rps and creates an infinite loop. How do I update message.content every new message?

```
if "s!rps" in message.content:
        MAI = message.author.id
        msg = "Do you pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors?".format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
        while True:
            cr = random.randint(1,3)
            if message.content.startswith("Rock"):
                if message.author.id == MAI:
                    choice = 1
                    break
            elif message.content.startswith("Paper"):
                if message.author.id == MAI:
                    choice = 2
                    break
            elif message.content.startswith("Scissors"):
                if message.author.id == MAI:
                    choice = 3
                    break
            elif message.content.startswith("rock"):
                if message.author.id == MAI:
                    choice = 1
                    break
            elif message.content.startswith("paper"):
                if message.author.id == MAI:
                    choice = 2
                    break
            elif message.content.startswith("scissors"):
                if message.author.id == MAI:
                    choice = 3
                    break
            else:
                if message.author.id == MAI:
                    if message.content != "s!rps":
                        msg = ("\"%s\" isn't a valid input." % message.content).format(message)
                        await client.send_message(message.channel,msg)    
        if choice == "Rock":
            choiceNum = 1
        if choice == "Paper":
            choiceNum = "2"
        if choice == 3:
            choiceWord = ""
        if cr == 1:
            crWord = "Rock"
        if cr == 2:
            crWord = "Paper"
        if cr == 3:
            crWord = "Scissors"
        if (cr-choice+5)%3 == 1:
            msg = ("You picked %s, I picked %s, you win!" % (choiceWord, crWord)).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
        if (cr-choice+5)%3 == 2:
            msg = ("You picked %s, I picked %s, I win!" % (choiceWord, crWord)).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
        if cr == choice:
            msg = ("We both picked %s, it's a tie." % choiceWord).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Comment: Which message do you want to change?  Where in your code do you want to change that message?

Comment: What exactly do you want to update?

Comment: the bot looks for  `"s!rps"` in the content of any new message, and when it finds `s!rps` in a message, or `message.content`, it begins looking for "Rock", "Paper", or "Scissors", the problem is, message.content stays as `"s!rps"` instead of changing every new message. In summary, i want to update `message.content`

Comment: So you want to wait for the user to edit their message to one of the choices?  The async branch doesn't have functionality to do this built in, but there may be a way by dynamically registering a listener for `on_message_edit` with the details of the edits you're looking for

Comment: I want the user's next message to be one of the choices.

Comment: It sounds like you want the user to type `s!rps` and then have the bot respond with a message for the user to select either rock, paper, or scissors. If you want to do that, just use `client.wait_for_message()` with a check so it will wait for the user to respond with their choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message content is fixed throughout your method, you never update or await a new message. Also that loop is potentially completely blocking your workflow! Drop the while loop and instead use `Client.wait_for_message` (or `Client.wait_for` if youre on rewrite).

I would do this as follows, define an inner function inside of the event that can be used as check when waiting for a specific message:

```
def check(m):
    answers = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    if any(answer == m.content.lower() for answer in answers):
        return True
    else:
        client.send_message(m.channel, "{0.content} is not a viable option".format(m))
        return False
```

Then, get rid of the while loop i.e modify your code to:

```
    MAI = message.author.id
    msg = "Do you pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors?".format(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    answer_msg = await client.wait_for_message(author = MAI, check = check)
    answer = answer_msg.content.lower()

    if answer == "rock":
        choice = 1
    elif answer == "scissors": 
    .....
```

Note that wait_for_message has an author parameter ensuring that the message author is indeed the one you want it to be, meaning that your `if message.author.id == MAI` will be accounted for. Also its now case insensitive.